# Ubuntu: pip version conflict

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ubuntu-16.04

pip told me, that i should update.
After i started the command

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

when i use

```
pip3 --version
```

i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 943, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 834, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 8.1.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==10.0.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 637, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==10.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I tried to install pip again:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

but it tells me

```
python3-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
```

How can i fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Similar to issue on Mac with Homebrew: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6784

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall it.

```
apt install --reinstall python3-pip
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this did not help.


Preparing to unpack .../python3-pip_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) over (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up python3-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...


But after i get the same error again.

Comment: So purge actual pip3, `apt-get purge python3-pip` and try to use "get_pip.py" script `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3`

Comment: I still get the same error after installing it this way.

Comment: I solved the problem by changing some folder permissions and renaming the old pip files in /usr/local/bin
Thanks.

Comment: Good, would be cool if you could share it here. It can help someone in a future.

Comment: I just did a chmod 777 to each folder the pip installer gave me.
It is shown in a red error message.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is still no real answer...
I also had this problem on Linux (CentOS 7) and managed to fix it.
Go to home folder.

```
$ cd ~
```

If you need the most recent version:

```
$ pip3 install --user --upgrade pip
```

If you need a specific version(like in the question)

```
$ pip3 install --user pip==10.0.1
```